# Should I test my controllers (MVC)?

Tags: model-view-controller, controller, mocking, tdd, integration-testing

I've been using TDD for several months, now I would like to learn how to test my Controllers (MVC).

Unit tests are made by testing the smallest unit of each functionality. Sometimes, controllers aren't small. They grab data from Models and pass then to the views.

How should I unit test a Controller? Should I mock controller's dependencies?

Are controllers tests considered integration tests?

Thank you.

Answer (score 23):

I'm doing TDD for quite long time. I'm doing TDD with ASP.NET MVC for more than year now.

I started with canonical rules: "no line of code without unit tests", so I tested everything - including the controllers. Controllers have to be tested, this was one of the goals of MVC framework - Make those stuff testable.

For small applications that approach works really well. Almost all logic is placed inside controller, everything very nicely tested.

But as long as I continued with MVC I started to change my mind. I try to keep controllers as slim as possible. Ideally nothing more as delegating the call to some business object and wrapping the results. The rest is by filters.

That worked nicely for me as well! I'm having now business object that are implemented/tested separately, so the controller is just integration point. No reason to test integration point since it is to small.

Regarding the integration tests: I haven't yet met the situation, where I actually need that. Don't forget, that controllers are always depend on abstractions that you inject by constructor. As long as you have 'good' assumptions how these abstractions work, you create proper unit tests. As you failed, you just correct the unit tests.

Integration tests are important and useful, but I try to create those as few as possible.

Comment: You write your model's test first, right? When do you write integration tests? May you cite an example?

Answer (score 7):

I take the same approach to controllers as Alexander B. My controllers are thin and dumb. However I still write tests for them to ensure they're calling the business or service objects correctly and passing the correct parameters.

This is probably best illustrated by an actual bug I finally caught last week. I have a controller that allows managers to approve or deny requests from users, it has two views, a list view of outstanding requests and a details view for each request. Both views can approve or deny. The service the controller calls to has a bunch of other exposed methods, including one for changing the status of requests... you can see where this is going. The list view called the correct method to approve or deny and trigger workflow, the details view only called the change status method, and didn't kick off any further workflow. This was my coding mistake, but for the life of me I couldn't see it for ages - the workflow runs in background threads, and I spent a week running down through those threads, assuming it was an error in that section.

So for me

- As soon as your controller passes data elsewhere it needs tests.
- If your controller checks model validity it needs tests (what if
  someone removed the check?)

etc.

Answer (score 4):

The same question asked yesterday:

[Does it make sense to test controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10196935/does-it-make-sense-to-test-controllers/)

And in my opinion - YES, it does make sense to test controllers. You can:

- mock services behind them, so it is easier to test just controllers itself
- leave services unmocked and do integration tests as well

Comment: Application Services https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/NLayer-Architecture#application-layer

Answer (score 3):

To develop a *unit test* for your controller, the natural way is to mock the interfaces the controller depends on (the 'things' it controls, let's call them `IControllable`s). Then you can verify that the controller manipulates the controlled objects in the expected way.

If the interaction between the controller and the controlled objects is complicated, dedicated *integration tests* may make sense. For example, there may be a series of classes implementing `IControllable` -- will each of these implementations work together nicely with the controller? Perhaps multiple different `IControllables` will interact (use the same resource)? Or the `IControllables` may have tricky ways to configure them affecting their behavior? A way to test this is to write a reusable test suite in which you pump in a range of suspicious `IControllable` implementations or combinations there of.

Last but not least, TDD is about *acceptance testing* as well. Thus, when doing TDD you will also have high level end-to-end test to execute scenarios an end-user would recognize. Most likely, these will exercise the controller as well -- in that way also testing the proper integration between your controller and (certain) classes.